# Why is that no articles used before "Once Upon a Time"?

Tags: articles

"**Once**" does sound vowel word,

then Why "**An**" is never used before this words "**Once Upon a Time**"?

Comment: Articles don't modify adverbs.

Comment: In this usage, "once" is an adverb.  It means in the past, but not now.  You could leave out "upon a time" without changing the meaning.  It can be used as a noun, but only after "for" or "at", as in "For once, I wish the three bears didn't leave their porridge out."  As a noun in that construction, it wouldn't need an article there, either.

Comment: "once" does not start with a vowel sound. It starts with the *consonant* sound /w/—the same as the word "wonder," and we say "**a** wonder." We don't use "an" before the sound /w/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Articles don't modify adverbs. – [user178049](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122127/why-is-that-no-articles-used-before-once-upon-a-time#comment246106_122127)

In this usage, "once" is an adverb. It means in the past, but not now. You could leave out "upon a time" without changing the meaning. It can be used as a noun, but only after "for" or "at", as in "For once, I wish the three bears didn't leave their porridge out." As a noun in that construction, it wouldn't need an article there, either. – [fixer1234](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122127/why-is-that-no-articles-used-before-once-upon-a-time#comment246107_122127)

Comment: I wrote that "upon a time" could be removed without changing anything.  That isn't precisely true.  "Once" refers to a timeframe, but doesn't address how often something happened.  "Upon a time" loosely means "on an occasion", so it adds clarification that the story refers to a specific event.  "Once upon a time" is equivalent to "On an occasion in the past".  The phrase is always assumed to refer to something that happened long ago rather than the recent past, so perhaps "On an occasion long ago".  Thought I'd better clarify that so people don't misunderstand their nursery rhymes.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Feel free to edit the community wiki to your heart's content. :)